# Python dbf: How to update a value?

Tags: python, dbf

so I am using python's dbf module (https://pypi.org/project/dbf/), and I want to update a key, value pair in a table. I have the following keys and values:

```
>>> for record in dbf.Process(table):
...     print record
...
  0 - store     : 590
  1 - date      : u'12/17/19'
  2 - check_num : 4
  3 - seq_main  : 1
  4 - option    : u'FALSE'
  5 - item_num  : 263
```

I want to update the 'date' field to datetime.date(2019, 12, 17). However, when I do the following:

```
>>> for record in dbf.Process(table):
...     record.date = datetime.date(2019, 12, 17)
...
```

I get the error:

```
File "/Users/me/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/dbf/__init__.py", line 3946, in update_character
    raise ValueError("unable to coerce %r(%r) to string" % (type(string), string))
ValueError: unable to coerce <type 'datetime.date'>(datetime.date(2019, 12, 17)) to string
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to convert the string date to a datetime object? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field is actually a character field -- it just happens to store date information in it.  You'll have to convert your date into text yourself and then save it:

```
>>> for record in dbf.Process(table):
...     record.date = datetime.date(2019, 12, 17).strftime('%m/%d/%y')
...
```

If your `date` field is 10 characters or more, change the `%y` to `%Y` to get a full 4-digit year.